# how is this call()-method in javascript is working?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about the call()-method in Javascript and trying to understand this ex.
Now my question are:

- Why I can't see anything in the console(browser); the console.log()-method; is not
  working?
- How is this anonymus-func working?

Thanks for yr time!

> ```
> var animals = [
>   {species: 'Lion', name: 'King'},
>   {species: 'Whale', name: 'Fail'}
> ];
>
> for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
>   (function (i) {
>     this.print = function () {
>       console.log('#' + i  + ' ' + this.species + ': ' + this.name);
>     }
>   }).call(animals[i], i); // I cant understand this anonymus func ? :(
> }
> ```

Comment: [MDN Docs on `call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: That example comes directly from the MDN docs. Pointing the OP back to where he came from won't do much good ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code to the end of your example:

```
animals[0].print();
```

The anonymous function is invoked using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which is used to set the `this` context within the body of the function. So when the anonymous function uses `this`, it is actually getting a referency to the current animal passed in from outside.

The function augments the `this` object (which is the currnet animal) with a `print` method. This alone will not display anything in the console. It merely means that the `print` method has been added to the animal object. But you can then access this method of the object with the code above.

Unfolding the loop, the code is effectively doing the following:

```
animals[0].print = function () {
    console.log('#' + 0  + ' ' + this.species + ': ' + this.name);
}

animals[1].print = function () {
    console.log('#' + 1  + ' ' + this.species + ': ' + this.name);
}
```

The key to understanding this example is to realise that without the use of `call`, the `this`reference in the anonymous function would automatically refer to the global `window` object. It would extend the `window`object with a `print` method, which obviously isn't what we want.

The next step example would be to obtain the same result by adding a `print`method to the object prototype. (This may well be the next example in your book)

Comment: ohh I c what u are saying and why the call()-method is taking in 2 arg:s.?

Comment: Take a look at the link to the `call` docs. The first parameter is passed in as the `this` context for the function. The rest of the parameters are passed to the function in the normal way. In other words, the second parameter to call becomes the first parameter passed into the function.

Comment: so one more comment about this: so the call-method should just work with one parameter uhn? -> call(animals[i]); right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. If you use just `.call(animals[i])` then the animal will be passed as the `this` context but no further paramters will be supplied to the function. In other words, the parameter `i` will be undefined.